# Can not install numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I am new to Python. I am trying to install numpy but I got this error.
Collecting ninja>=1.8.2
Using cached ninja-1.11.1.tar.gz (27 kB)
Installing build dependencies: started
Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
Getting requirements to build wheel: started
Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'done'
Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): started
Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): finished with status 'done'
Building wheels for collected packages: ninja
Building wheel for ninja (pyproject.toml): started
Building wheel for ninja (pyproject.toml): finished with status 'error'
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

```
    Building wheel for ninja (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
    exit code: 1

    [9 lines of output]
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-9e2mdrtx\overlay\lib\python3.10\site-packages\skbuild\setuptools_wrap.py", line 645, in setup
        cmkr = cmaker.CMaker(cmake_executable)
      File "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-9e2mdrtx\overlay\lib\python3.10\site-packages\skbuild\cmaker.py", line 148, in __init__
        self.cmake_version = get_cmake_version(self.cmake_executable)
      File "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-9e2mdrtx\overlay\lib\python3.10\site-packages\skbuild\cmaker.py", line 105, in get_cmake_version
        raise SKBuildError(msg) from err

    Problem with the CMake installation, aborting build. CMake executable is cmake
    [end of output]

    note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
    ERROR: Failed building wheel for ninja
  Failed to build ninja
  ERROR: Could not build wheels for ninja, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
  [end of output]
```

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× pip subprocess to install backend dependencies did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.

can anyone tell me whats the problem is? and how to fix it

Comment: How is cmake installed?

Comment: I think this issue is related to the CMake installation. Try Upgrade pip like **pip install --upgrade pip**, After, you may need to install CMake on your system. Then Upgrade setuptools and wheel to the latest versions like **pip install --upgrade setuptools wheel** , and finally try installing numpy again: **pip install numpy**

Answer (score 1):

Here are some steps you can try to resolve this issue:

**1 - Upgrade pip**

```
pip install --upgrade pip
```

**2- Install CMake**

```
apt-get install cmake
```

**3- Upgrade Setuptools and Wheel**

```
pip install --upgrade setuptools wheel
```

**4- Install numpy: Try installing numpy again:**

```
pip install numpy
```

Comment: The wheel upgrade solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

Pip failed to install the package `ninja`, which is necessary for you to use `numpy`.

Here is the message: `Failed building wheel for ninja`

It also says that it failed because of an error with `CMake`.

Here is the message: `Problem with the CMake installation, aborting build.`

To solve this, try to install `CMake` with this line: `apt-get install cmake`.